# Reading JSON in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I receive the following JSON data from a web service in Angular 4:

```
    {
        "NewDataSet": {
            "Table": [
                {
                    "DataPointID": [
                        "6520"
                    ]
               }
           ]
       }
    }
```

I have verified that it is valid JSON data, but when I try to return, I don't get the value. I received it as a string and I converted it into JSON using `JSON.Stringfy(obj,null,'\t')`

`obj.NewDataSet.Table[0].DataPointID` throws

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Table' of undefined.

I tried this on w3School in html, but it seems that it's working there. What is the issue?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` turns an object into a string, not the other way around. It seems like you either want to use `JSON.parse` or you already have an object to work with and you don't have to do any parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an interface and let know the get that it must return the value in the interface type. So your code might look something like the following:

```
export interface ThisGetInterfaceResponse {
    "NewDataSet": NewDataSetModel
}

export class NewDataSetModel {
    "Table": Table[]
}

export class Table {
   constructor(
      "DataPointID": number[]
   ) {}
}
```

Let's say you have httpService that is an instance of HttpClient injected in your component:

```
this.httpService.get<ThisGetInterfaceResponse>(url).subscribe((res: ThisGetInterfaceResponse) => {
   console.log(res.NewDataSet.Table);
})
```

Also pay attention to `.subscribe()` because if you subscribe to the observer multiple times it will request the resource multiple times.
For example:

`let observable = this.httpService.get<ResponseInterface>(url);
observable.subscribe();
observable.subscribe();
...`

Answer (score 0):

when you get the object you should read it as

```
this.http.get(ServiceUrls.employees.detail(this.operations.userID)).subscribe(
      detail => this.RequestSuccess(detail.json()), (error: Response) => this.RequestError(error.json())
    );
```

Notice there is a detail.json() so in your function you don't have to do anything else.